# R variable number of string concatenations within group_by

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

Let's say I have the following table of houses (or anything) and their colors:

[image: Houses]

I'm trying to:

1. group_by(Group)
2. count rows (I assume with `length(unique(ID))`,
3. mutate or summarize into a new row with a count of each color in group, as a string.

Result should be:

[image: Houses with summary]

So I know step 3 *could* be done by manually entering every possible combination with something like

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(
    Summary = case_when(
      all(
        sum(count_green) > 0
        ) ~ paste(length(unique(ID)), " houses, ", count_green, " green")
    )
  )
```

but what if I have hundreds of possible combinations? Is there a way to paste into a string and append for each new color/count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach where we count the frequency of 'Group', 'Color' with `add_count`, `unite` that with 'Color', then grouped by 'Group', create the 'Summary' column by concatenating the `unique` elements of 'nColor' with the frequency (`n()`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
    add_count(Group, Color) %>%
    unite(nColor, n, Color, sep= ' ',  remove = FALSE) %>%
    group_by(Group) %>% 
    mutate(
        Summary = str_c(n(), ' houses, ', toString(unique(nColor))))  %>%
    select(-nColor) 
# Groups:   Group [2]
#     ID Group Color      n Summary                    
#  <int> <chr> <chr>  <int> <chr>                      
#1     1 a     Green      2 3 houses, 2 Green, 1 Orange
#2     2 a     Green      2 3 houses, 2 Green, 1 Orange
#3     3 a     Orange     1 3 houses, 2 Green, 1 Orange
#4     4 b     Blue       2 3 houses, 2 Blue, 1 Yellow 
#5     5 b     Yellow     1 3 houses, 2 Blue, 1 Yellow 
#6     6 b     Blue       2 3 houses, 2 Blue, 1 Yellow
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:6, Group = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"
), Color = c("Green", "Green", "Orange", "Blue", "Yellow", "Blue"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach with `map_chr` from `purrr` and a lot of pasting.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(Summary = paste(n(),"houses,",
                          paste(map_chr(unique(as.character(Color)),
                                        ~paste(sum(Color == .x),.x)),
                                collapse = ", ")))

## A tibble: 6 x 4
## Groups:   Group [2]
#     ID Group Color  Summary                    
#  <int> <fct> <fct>  <chr>                      
#1     1 a     Green  3 houses, 2 Green, 1 Orange
#2     2 a     Green  3 houses, 2 Green, 1 Orange
#3     3 a     Orange 3 houses, 2 Green, 1 Orange
#4     4 b     Blue   3 houses, 2 Blue, 1 Yellow 
#5     5 b     Yellow 3 houses, 2 Blue, 1 Yellow 
#6     6 b     Blue   3 houses, 2 Blue, 1 Yellow
```